# jQuery: set 'selected' tag in options if value is in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectedindex

I'm trying to add the `selected` attribute to the `option` tag using jQuery (on a Wordpress site). The values that should be selected are stored in a PHP array. Why does the `selected` attribute not get added to the `<option>..` ?

**my-script.js**

```
jQuery("#location option").each(function($){

var arr = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $php_array).'"' ?>];
// for testing also hardcoded array: doesn't work either
// var arr = ["1", "2"];

   if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(),arr) != -1){
     $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
   };

});
```

The `.js` script is properly enqueqed.

**html-output**

```
   <select name="location[]" multiple="multiple" id="location" class="postform" style="display: none;">
            <option value="-1">Select a location</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="1">Location A</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="2">Location B</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="3">Location C</option>

        </select>
```

Comment: Tip: Use `json_encode` to inject the PHP array into the JavaScript source: `var arr = <?php echo json_encode($php_array) ?>;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you cannot pass anything to the `each` handler. Remove the `$` from that and your code works fine:

```
var arr = ["1", "2"];
jQuery("#location option").each(function () {
    if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), arr) != -1) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
    };
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LcPmu/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have typo in jQuery loop

```
jQuery("#location option").each(function($){

var arr = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $php_array).'"' ?>];
// for testing also hardcoded array: doesn't work either
// var arr = ["1", "2"];

   if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(),arr) != -1){
     $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
   };

});
```

function($) should be without parameter, like this function()

Working code:

```
jQuery("#location option").each(function(){

var arr = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $php_array).'"' ?>];
// for testing also hardcoded array: doesn't work either
// var arr = ["1", "2"];

   if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(),arr) != -1){
     $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
   };

});
```

my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cs329/